# Replace SWF Resources without having to decompile?

Tags: flash

I want to replace an image inside of a SWF File without the need to decompile it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible, you need to recompile the swf file.

Comment: I found this http://code.google.com/p/swfreplacer/ and it appears to be possible... but I can't get this one working, maybe it only works in the older version of flash.

Comment: It is updated at 2009, so probably supports only older version of swf. The problema is that with every new version of swf file format, its bytecode specs changes, so that program would be updated.